# An ODE problem that seems weird!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image: Linear ODE - Non Homogeneous]

Well, as you can see in the image above, the problem consists of a Linear-Non Homogeneous ODE. It goes on and tasks the student with transforming such ODE into a Linear 4th Order ODE containing only the variable Y1. It states then that this ODE is Non-Homogeneous as well.

However as I was solving the first step of the problem ( using the procedure described in the link: http://homepage.ntu.edu.tw/~ihwang/Teaching/Fall13/Slides/DE_Lecture_07_handout_v2.pdf) I stumbled upon a big issue: the new ODE that had arisen was Homogeneous! Am I doing anything wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No, you're not doing anything wrong (that I can see).  A linear DE is homogeneous iff $0$ is a solution.  It happens in this case that $Y = \pmatrix{0\cr 0\cr 0\cr 1\cr}$ is a solution of your system  (because $-\phi$ happens to be the fourth column of $A$).  Therefore any linear DE for $Y_1$
(or, for that matter, $Y_2$ or $Y_3$) will have to be homogeneous.

The procedure to produce a higher-order linear DE from a nonhomogeneous system will generally produce a nonhomogeneous DE, but occasionally that DE will turn out to be homogeneous.

Comment: Ummm so I implemented such method in a small Matlab script and I received the following answer for Y1: D^4*Y1 +0.3D^3*Y1 + 0.3D^2*Y1 - D^3 = 0. What is the meaning of the D all by itself? @RobertIsrael

Comment: That depends on what you put in your Matlab script (probably not the right thing...)

Comment: Here follows the code!

syms D y1 y2 y3 y4

Lmatrix= [ (D-1) 2 1 1; -0.5 D+1 0.5 0.5; -0.1 -0.1 D+0.1 0.1; -0.2 0.1 0.2 D+0.2];

L = det(Lmatrix);
phi = [ 1 0.5 0.1 0.2]';
phinew = sym(phi);

g1matrix=[phinew,Lmatrix(:,2:4)];
g2matrix=[Lmatrix(:,1),phinew,Lmatrix(:,3:4)];
g3matrix=[Lmatrix(:,1:2),phinew,Lmatrix(:,4)];
g4matrix=[Lmatrix(:,1:3),phinew];

g1 = det(g1matrix);
g2 = det(g2matrix);
g3 = det(g3matrix);
g4 = det(g4matrix);

expand(L*y1-g1)

Comment: Sorry forgot to mark you in the comment! @RobertIsrael

Comment: I'm not sure what you think that code is doing, but it's certainly not finding the DE for Y1.